# What if Pinatubo's eruption in 1991 had been followed by a La Niña rather than an El Niño?

Tags: atmosphere, climate, volcanology, enso

If there had been a La Niña rather than an El Niño in 1991-92, would the sulfur aerosol veil caused by the release of 17-20 megatons of sulfur dioxide during the Pinatubo eruption of June 1991 have caused an even greater amount of global cooling - and with much more social/economic disruption - than it actually did?

(It's just because I've read that the global cooling effects of Pinatubo were quite possibly mitigated by the El Niño that followed the eruption - and that the eruption and the El Niño were coincidental and not cause-and-effect.)